# Create equal-size bins over given range

Tags: r, bins

I want to create bins of equal size up to certain number.
Example: for I want to create bin of size 10, over the range 0..100

```
0 10
10 20
20 30
.
.
.
90 100
```

I tried using "cut" but couldnt make it work for my purpose.
I used

```
r<-cut(100,4)
```

but it returned

```
[1] (99.95,100]
Levels: (99.9,99.95] (99.95,100] (100,100.05] (100.05,100.1]
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what "couldn't make it work for my purpose" means.

Comment: The first arg to cut needs to be a vector, not a single number: `cut(0:100,)` instead of `cut(100,..` That's all you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the help page: `?cut`.

`cut(100,4)` tries to cut the single entry vector (100) into 4 different bins. In this call, `cut` cannot know whether you want the bins to cover the interval [0,100] with your bins, or [50,100], or [99.9,100.1], so it has to make some assumptions.

`cut(1:100,breaks=10*(0:10))` may do what you want, or even `levels(cut(100,breaks=10*(0:10)))`, depending on what exactly you want to do with the result.

Comment: Admittedly, `cut` could trivially easy reject a first argument which was not a vector. But instead it plods along and gives this bizarre behavior when given an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Let

```
v <- seq(0, 100, 10)
# [1]   0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

be a vector.

You can use `cut` to specify the intervals:

```
cut(v, seq(0, 100, 10), include.lowest = TRUE)
# [1] [0,10]   [0,10]   (10,20]  (20,30]  (30,40]  (40,50]  (50,60]  (60,70]  (70,80]  (80,90]  (90,100]
# Levels: [0,10] (10,20] (20,30] (30,40] (40,50] (50,60] (60,70] (70,80] (80,90] (90,100]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for :

```
cbind(seq(0,90,by=10),seq(10,100,10))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0   10
 [2,]   10   20
 [3,]   20   30
 [4,]   30   40
 [5,]   40   50
 [6,]   50   60
 [7,]   60   70
 [8,]   70   80
 [9,]   80   90
[10,]   90  100
```